# Calling an action method asynchronously doesn't load the view

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-ajax

I have 2-3 partial views in a view. Each of these have web service calls.
These are synchronous calls like following.  I want to load the Address partial view asynchronously. I am trying to make it load using ajax.In document ready()

Can i remove the Action call to Address/Index from Personal View line as i would be loading the view via ajax?
If i don't remove it then it errors out saying that the Model is not passed and if i remove it then the partial view doesn't load. What am i doing wrong?

Also, the Personal view and the Address view are in different folders. is this what is causing it not to load?

Personal View:

```
<div id="PersonalInfo">
  Html.Action("_Index", PersonalInfo)
</div>
<div id="Address">
  Html.Action("../Address/_Index", Address)   // Can i remove this line as i would be loading the 
                                                view via ajax?
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Address")',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (result) {
            $('#Address').html(result); // where #Address is the div id in Address Partial View
        }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Address View

```
 <div id="Address">
    // address displayed in a grid
  </div>
```

Address controller

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //call service and get List<Address>()
        var address= getAddress();

        return this.PartialView("_Index", address);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datatype should be HTML.

```
<div id="PersonalInfo">
  Html.Action("_Index", PersonalInfo)
</div>
<div id="Address">
  Html.Action("../Address/_Index", Address)   // Can i remove this line as i would be loading the 
                                                view via ajax?
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Address")',
        dataType: 'HTML',
        success: function (result) {
            $('#Address').html(result); // where #Address is the div id in Address Partial View
        }
    });
  });
</script>
Address View
```

Answer (score 4):

You've got a few problems here:

1. Incorrect razor syntax
2. Incorrect use of the `Action` extension method
3. Issuing incorrect async requests with the jQuery plugin

### 1. Incorrect razor syntax

This...

```
<div id="PersonalInfo">
   Html.Action("_Index", PersonalInfo)
</div>
```

should be using the `@` escape character to instruct razor to stop processing html and start processing razor syntax. Here's how you should use it...

```
<div id="PersonalInfo">
   @Html.Action("_Index", PersonalInfo)
</div>
```

Make sure that the `_Index` action method exists in whatever controller you're calling here

### 2. Incorrect use of the `Action` extension method

This...

```
<div id="Address">
  Html.Action("../Address/_Index", Address)   
</div>
```

will definitely throw exceptions of all kinds because the first parameter of this overload must be the name of Action method you are trying to invoke. If this action method is in different controller (different from the current context), you should use a different overload that allows you to specify the controller name like below...

```
<div id="Address">
  Html.Action("Index", "Address", null)   
</div>
```

you should notice two things here:

- The name of your action method is "Index", not "_Index"
- Based on the code snippet you posted, this action method does NOT expect any routed values so I've passed in `null`

### 3. Issuing incorrect async requests with the jQuery plugin

As noted by @dotnetstep, this jQuery ajax method...

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Address")',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (result) {
        $('#Address').html(result);
    }
 });
```

should have the `dataType` option set to `html` because the action method method you are invoking responds data in html format not json. Even better, you don't need to specify anything at all jQuery will do a smart guess...

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Address")',
    success: function (result) {
        $('#Address').html(result);
    }
 });
```